# Codeigniter Insert Dynamic multiple input

Tags: codeigniter-3

can someone help me please. im stock. Can you help me how to save multiple value from multiple dynamic textbox?

My View:

```
 <?php
  echo form_open(admin/add_transaction); 
  for ($i=0; $i < $qty ; $i++) { 
  $count = $i+1; 
  $newinput=array(
     'class'=>"form-control",
     'name'=>"$property_no-$count",
     'placeholder'=>"Serial No. - $property_no-$count",
                 ); ?>
                               <div class="input-group">
                               <span class="input-group-addon">
                               <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode"></i></span>
                              <?php echo form_input($newinput); ?></div>
                               <br>
                               <?php }
                               echo form_close();
                                ?>
```

My Controller:

```
        function add_transaction(){
        $this->masterrecords->save_serial();
        redirect('admin/transaction');
    }
```

My Model: How to insert multiple value of input text?

```
        function save_serial(){

        $s=$this->input->post('new');

        $data = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->input->post('new')); $i++)
    {
        $data = array(

            'serial_no' => $s[$i],


        );
    }
        $this->db->insert('tblserial_no' ,$data);
        return true;



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `$qty` and `$property_no` variable with you. What you can do is create two hidden fields for both the variables:

```
 <input type='hidden' name='qty' value='<?= $qty ?>'/>
 <input type='hidden' name='property_no' value='<?= $property_no ?>'/>
  
 //then in your model:
 $data = array();
 for ($i=0; $i < $this->input->post('qty') ; $i++) { 

       $count = $i+1;

       //check fields are set and not empty...
       if($this->input->post($this->input->post('property_no').'-'.$count) && 
          $this->input->post($this->input->post('property_no').'-'.$count) != ""){

          //prepare your $data array.. 
          $data[$count] = $this->input->post($this->input->post('property_no').'-'.$count);

       }
  }
```